# Is there an option to configure watch or listener on ConfigMap and Secret resource

Tags: kubernetes

Is there an annotation or the way to configure external actions for implementing an internal logic when there is a change in the Configmap / Secret resource object.

```
kind: ConfigMap
....
data:
key1:val1
key2:val2
```

When there is a change in ConfigMap resource (key3:val3 is added), provide an annotation/way to configure some action where internal logic can be implemented. My internal logic for example can be rollout restart deployment to take these changes freshly.(example scenario : The action can be a python file where i will run the deployment rollout).

Why is this needed:
Watching the mounted file system continuously inside the pod/container with a kubelet sync period + cache propagation delay may introduce some delay. This will affect the application logic implementation which has to happen immediately.

Comment: You might read up on Kubernetes [controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/controller/).  You can also create a [custom resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/) that describes your deployment configuration, for the controller to act on; if you put the two parts together, it is an [operator](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/) and there are tools to simplify building them.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @sriniev and welcome on Stack Overflow

the pattern you are looking for (watch for changes in ConfigMap and react upon it) is used for instance by [prometheus operator](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/667aa8f3d7404115a2dd7ca65815252aeb4be5c4/cmd/prometheus-config-reloader/main.go) or as a standalone project/binary called [configmap-reload](https://github.com/jimmidyson/configmap-reload/blob/master/README.md), that can run in the sidecar container.

Please try to borrow from them some key logic.

Comment: Hi @Nepomucen, I have a requirement for generic listener pattern. I think the above pattern will work only when it is single configmap to monitor. Or I may end-up in running side-car containers in each microservice pods. Because my end action is to rollout the deployment set when there is a change in ConfigMap content and I am thinking the race conditions when replica count is more than 1.

microservice-configmap
microservice-1-poda : microservice-1's app container, microservice-1's sidecarcontainer
microservice-1-podb : microservice-1's app container, microservice-1's sidecarcontainer

Comment: @sriniev, you may consider also to use a more generic kubernetes watcher from bitnami, which enables to subscribe to most of popular K8S resources than ConfigMap only. Please take a look at their project [here](https://github.com/bitnami-labs/kubewatch).